# Concurrency with JMS topic in Spring

Tags: java, concurrency, jms, jms-topic

How to use concurrency in jms topics using spring? Like for queues we can set maxConcurrentConsumers properties to the desired number. But if I do that for a JMS topic, it leads to concurrent consumption of the same message, which is not desirable.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: That's how topics work. You are using the wrong kind of JMS destination for your purpose. Use a JMS Queue destination instead.

Comment: Then why does ejb allow that? Actually I am migrating an existing ejb project to spring and Thats how its done in ejb.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) in a wrong way. From the docs:

> Note that dynamic scaling only really makes sense for a queue in the first place; for a topic, you will typically stick with the default number of 1 consumer, else you'd receive the same message multiple times on the same node.

To help your situation you may forward messages from the topic to a queue and let your consumers consume from this queue. If your JMS provider has some forwarding feature, than this is merely a configuration change to your application.

Comment: Correct! But our application is huge and we get thousands of messages per hour!! Also, there are 5 different topics that point to the same listener class. In that case particularly, concurrency is needed to make the processing quick. Since there is no way I can achieve that through topics, I'm thinking of making changes in the code of my listener class (the one which listens to 4 different topics). For now, I am considering using a task executor which implements some sort of threading logic to internally manage the processing. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!! :)

Comment: @user3544133 *thousands of messages per hour* you do realize that is actually very little, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well you said it yourself in a comment, but just to elaborate.

Inside your listener, you can still create multiple threads and execute the processing in an *asynchronous way*. As soon as you get your messages dispatch it to a asynchronous consumer. This is fairly easily implemented through some sort of executor for example.

*I would really go for the guava's EventBus*. It is so simple, yet so easy to set up and use.
But this is your choice really.